# JavaEE: Bean Managed Transaction

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, entitymanager

I want to start parallel write process with some requirements.

1. One commit only, to avoid inconsistent data
2. rollback all when any of the threads is failed

I am using Hibernate as ORM mapper and want to solve it by using a custom managed transaction.

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class Manager {

       @EJB
       private Dao dao;

       @Resource
       private SessionContext sessionContext;

       private static ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = initThreadPoolExecutor();

       private ThreadLocal<UserTransaction> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<UserTransaction>();

       public void write(BasicRequest req) {
             UserTransaction mainTransaction = sessionContext.getUserTransaction();
           //  threadLocal.set(mainTransaction);

             try {
                    mainTransaction.begin();
                    execute(req.getNewObjects(), this::createObject);
                    mainTransaction.commit();
             } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // mainTransaction.rollback(); // -- Include this in try-catch
             }
       }

       @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
       public void execute(List<BasicElement> elements, Function<Void, String> function)
                    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
             final List<Future<?>> futureElements = new ArrayList<>();
             for (BasicElement el : elements) {
                    futureElements.add(threadPoolExecutor.submit(() -> {
                          function.apply(el);
                    }));
             }
             grapResults(futureElements);
       }

       @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
       public Void createObject(BasicElement el) {
             BasicEntity be = convert(el);
             dao.persist(be);
       }
}

@Stateless
@Local
public class Dao {

       @PersistenceContext(unitName = "basic")
       protected EntityManager em;
       
       
       public void persist(Object entity) {
             em.persist(entity);
       }
}
```

So with above code, I cannot get it worked.
I dont know how to tell each created thread to use the same UserTransaction or use the same entity manager. I have to make the UserTransaction thread safe, but do not know how to interact further.